# Sending emails through GoDaddy - connection refused

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

I want to send email from the webhost GoDaddy using a PHO script.
This is my configuration:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net';
$config['smtp_port'] = 468;
```

When I try to send email I get this error message:

```
unable to connect to ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net:468 (Connection refused)
```

Does GoDaddy need some configuration? This error happen only when I send the email via GoDaddy. When I send it from my localhost the email is sent successfully.

What am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to use mail without configuration of smtp, godaddy has it's own mail server so it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy has it's [own SMTP relay servers](http://help.godaddy.com/article/3552), and will (probably) block your own SMTP ports if you do try to set up one. SMTP settings are unique to each account, so make sure you configure them correctly. There is a limit of 250 outgoing emails per day. If you are hosted on a Windows environment, you'll need to add your SMTP settings in php.ini for your mails to be sent correctly.